# pressing a button and going to a previous layout

Tags: java, android, button, layout, android-activity

does anyone has any idea how to press a button and go to one of my previous layouts?

```
public class Main extends Activity {

private Button button_back;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            setContentView(R.layout.back);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Back.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

well that's the main idea, but android doesn't also recognize as types my buttons as well

Comment: You can also fire a `super.onBackPressed()` in your on click listener.

Comment: To make your life easy ( just my guess ), you may want to use Fragment instead of Views.

Comment: like.. @Override
public void onBackPressed() {   
return; }

Comment: i changed it, but know it crashes

Comment: OK, I guess I don't quite get what you are asking. If you have tow activities, and when the back_button press, call `finish()`, which will brings you back to your previous. If you only want to have one activity, then use `Fragment`, when back_button press, switch Fragment using `FragmentManager`.

Comment: i simply want to press a button and go to my previous layout!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Intent`.

Simply

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, Other_Activity.class);
startActivity(intent;
```

try this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Answer (score 0):

i think if view is fixed then you should use viewflipper. and just use shownext and showprevious on button click to show previous view.